# Split lines of space-delimited values to get flat array of 2nd and 3rd column values

Tags: php, arrays, text-extraction, preg-split, delimited

I have the following data which is displaying as this

```
{123456  123456  123456}
{654321  654321  654321}
{123456  123456  123456}
```

My PHP Code:

```
$myarray = preg_split("/(\s|{\s)/", $data);
print_r($myarray);
```

The output of my array is like this:

```
[0] => {123456
[1] => 123456
[2] => 123456}
[3] => {654321
[4] => 654321
[5] => 654321}
[6] => {123456
[7] => 123456
[8] => 123456}
```

My question is, how to hide [0], [3] and [6] from the output? if you noticed, they start with a `{`
I'm not sure if I did a mistake coding the `preg_split` function

Desired behavior:

if the data is like this

```
{1  2  3}
{4  5  6}
{7  8  9}
```

the desired output should be like this:

```
[0] => 2
[1] => 3
[2] => 5
[3] => 6
[4] => 8
[5] => 9
```

Comment: why not remove the curly braces before the regex using `str_replace` or similar?

Comment: because the curly braces are generated along with the data itself, do you have any idea how to get rid of it, however even if you can do it, i still don't need that data in array[0],[1] and [3] to be displayed at all

Comment: what criteria is there to either hiding or displaying the resultant numbers? There are duplicates in the data - that presumably is fine?

Comment: array[0] must be hidden, array[1] must be visible, array [2] must be visible then array[3] must be hidden, the numbers are only for making examples, i can't share real data

Comment: Why are you using `preg_split()` instead of `preg_match_all()` to get the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Change `{\s` to `{\d+\s` so that `{123456` will be a delimiter and not be included in the result.

You don't need the capture group around the regular expression.

```
$data = '{123456  123456  123456}
{654321  654321  654321}
{123456  123456  123456}';
$myarray = preg_split("/\s|{\d+\s/", $data);
print_r($myarray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 123456
    [3] => 
    [4] => 123456}
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 654321
    [8] => 
    [9] => 654321}
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] => 123456
    [13] => 
    [14] => 123456}
)
```

If you also don't want `}` in the results, that needs to be in the regexp as well.

```
$myarray = preg_split("/\s+|\s*\{\d+\s*|\s*\}\s*/", $data);
```

You could also use a regular expression that matches a number unless it's preceded by `{`, using a negative lookbehind.

```
$data = '{1 2 3} {4 5 6} {7 8 9}';
preg_match_all('/(?<!{)\d+/', $data, $match);
$myarray = $match[0];
print_r($myarray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 9
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for your input, if the data is like this

   ` {1  2  3}
    {4  5  6}
    {7  8  9}`

the desired output should be like this:

    `[0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 9`

please check my question edit

Comment: You can remove the empty elements with `array_filter()`.

Comment: I don't know why the solution provided didn't work out for my production code. but it does work if I hardcode the data in the array as you did.

Comment: Your original question didn't say anything about removing the `}` at the end of elements 2, 5, and 8. But your edit doesn't have them.

Comment: I get `[0] => 
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3}
    [3] => 
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6}
    [6] => 
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9}`

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything needs a regular expression.

```php
$input = <<<_E_
{123456  123456  123456}
{654321  654321  654321}
{123456  123456  123456}
_E_;

$lines = explode("\n", $input);
$lines = array_map(function($a){return trim($a, '{}');}, $lines);
$lines = array_map(function($a){return explode(' ', $a);}, $lines);
$lines = array_map('array_filter', $lines);
$items = array_merge(...$lines);

var_dump($lines, $items);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "123456"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "123456"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "123456"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "654321"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "654321"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "654321"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "123456"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "123456"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "123456"
  }
}
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "654321"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "654321"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "654321"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  [8]=>
  string(6) "123456"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right. There should only be 2 matches per row, not 3. It shouldn't include the first number after `{`.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything needs a regular expression, but sometimes it is the most direct tool for the job.

Split the string on all characters that you don't want to keep.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/O5FIc))

```
var_export(
    preg_split(
        '/ +|}\R?|{\d+/',
        $text,
        0,
        PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `preg_split()` is required, but you could do this with a match all and then gather what's found:

```
$foo = trim('
{555555  123456  123456}
{666666  654321  654321}
{777777  123456  123456}
');

$items = [];

if (preg_match_all('/^{[\d]{1,}  ([\d]{1,})  ([\d]{1,})}$/m', $foo, $matches)) {
    $items = array_reduce(
        array_slice($matches, 1),
        fn(array $found, array $match) => array_merge($found, $match),
        []
    );
}

var_dump($items);
```

Gives:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "654321"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "654321"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "123456"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/n9tRk